# why the nodemon run on my backend forever if I inappropriately close it?

Tags: nodemon

when I install my nodemon I used --force, but now if I not close my nodemon with clt + C, it will run at the backend forever, I could not use my same localhost:3000 again.
The only way I can close it is restart my computer.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the bottom of your root file
`process.on('SIGINT', () => process.exit(1));`

And also if the error still happens you dont need to restart your system, just simple kill the port 3000 and you will be able to reuse it